# Intergrate Social Tools in CMS

Tags: content-manager

I have the requirement to integrate the social media tool like linkden,facebook etc in SDL tridion CMS. On the published pages there would be one button called "Share" when the end user click on it the corresponding content shoould get post on social media like facebook,twitter etc.

Please help!

Comment: Where are you trying to integrate Social Media (and how?)... On your published website? In the Content Manager Explorer? What is the integration supposed to do? Most importantly... What have you already tried? Please make your question less broad.

Comment: i want to share the paublished site page content as post on social media in tridion

Comment: Is this actually a Tridion question?

Answer (score 6):

You can refer the community extension page - [SDL Tridion Community Extension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/index.aspx) -which consists of various community add on that you can use with your SDL Tridion implementations.

Various Social Media add-ons are available here, few of them are listed below:

- [Facebook Social Plugin](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/FacebookExtensions.aspx)
- [Twitter Extension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/twitter.aspx)
- [Linked In Extension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/linkedin.aspx)

You can evaluate these to match your need or you can further implement as per your need.

Also, you can scan through this community extension page and if you do not found a plug in for your need you can always implement as you do in traditional .NET application, integrate it with Tridion and also think of share it here so that it could be useful to others.

Answer (score 5):

Below is one of implementation we have on a project. i hope you have basic understanding how social sharing works.

1. Provide User an options in Tridion (using component) to select the required Social networks, (fb, twitter, g+),order, icons(for share feature only),  because "like" feature cannot have custom images.
2. Publish the page as UserControl.
3. Use Social Network service such as [Addthis](http://www.addthis.com), and filter the addthis using options(from step 1), so that it shows only selected networks on the page.
4. Include that UserControl on the page.
5. For open Graph tags you can use Master page and to override og properties use page Metadata.